# remove the unicode from the output of JSON using scrapy

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy

from ex.items import ExItem

class reddit(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["reddit.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.reddit.com/"]

    """docstring for reddit"""
    def parse(self, response):
        item = ExItem()
        item ["title"] = response.xpath('//p[contains(@class,"title")]/a/text()').extract()
        item ["rank"] = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"rank")]/text()').extract()
        item ["votes_dislike"] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"score dislikes")]/text()').extract()
        item ["votes_unvoted"] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"score unvoted")]/text()').extract()
        item ["votes_likes"] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"score likes")]/text()').extract()
        item ["video_reference"] = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"thumbnail may-blank")]/@href').extract()
        item ["image"] = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"thumbnail may-blank")]/img/@src').extract()
```

I am able to convert this into JSON but in the output i am getting a bullet in the JSON how to remove that and still have the JSON format?

Comment: i want to remove it completely from my json output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hidden elements that you don't see in the browser. Scrapy sees them.

You just need to search for the data inside the relevant part of the page (`div` with `id="siteTable"`):

```
def parse(self, response):
    # make a selector and search the fields inside it
    sel = response.xpath('//div[@id="siteTable"]')

    item = ExItem()
    item["title"] = sel.xpath('.//p[contains(@class,"title")]/a/text()').extract()
    item["rank"] = sel.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"rank")]/text()').extract()
    item["votes_dislike"] = sel.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"score dislikes")]/text()').extract()
    item["votes_unvoted"] = sel.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"score unvoted")]/text()').extract()
    item["votes_likes"] = sel.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"score likes")]/text()').extract()
    item["video_reference"] = sel.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"thumbnail may-blank")]/@href').extract()
    item["image"] = sel.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"thumbnail may-blank")]/img/@src').extract()
    return item
```

Tested, here is what I get for, for example, `votes_likes`:

```
 'votes_likes': [u'5340',
                 u'4041',
                 u'4080',
                 u'5055',
                 u'4385',
                 u'4784',
                 u'3842',
                 u'3734',
                 u'4081',
                 u'3731',
                 u'4580',
                 u'5279',
                 u'2540',
                 u'4345',
                 u'2068',
                 u'3715',
                 u'3249',
                 u'4232',
                 u'4025',
                 u'522',
                 u'2993',
                 u'2789',
                 u'3529',
                 u'3450',
                 u'3533'],
```